# How to get the post content after Wordpress post processing?

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin that will send tutorial emails to our users. These tutorials are created in wordpress and stored in wp_posts table in the database.

Of course I could simply run a query to get the post and that's it. But is there a special built-in function that I can use to get the post content after Wordpress post processing?

I am thing of using get_post but I'm not sure if this is the best thing to do:

```
<?php
$my_id = 7;
$post_id_7 = get_post($my_id); 
$post_content = $post_id_7->post_content;
?>
```

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: By "after post processing", do you mean you want the content with the html edited (<p> tags added, etc), or do you just mean after the post has been saved?

Comment: Yes I mean all formatting and all processing..not after the post has been saved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "post processing" you mean the autoformatting, the shortcode processing, that sort of thing, then you want to pass the content through the `the_content` filters.

```
$my_id = 7;
$post_id_7 = get_post($my_id); 
$post_content = $post_id_7->post_content;
$post_content = apply_filters('the_content',$post_content);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters

You can see much of what will be applied by default by looking at the source of [`wp-includes/default-filters.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/default-filters.php). However, plugins and themes can add filters so you may find that you want to pick and choose what gets applieds.